# how to measure each product screen view firebase_analytics

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm trying firebase_analytics to log user events I can log current screen name with `setCurrentScreen(screenName)` but how I can send parameters like in product details screen I want to log product id and do analytics on how much a product screen was viewed
something like this:
`setCurrentScreen(screenName: "product_details", parameters: {"productId": 1})`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to manually track screen_view event on your app. You can include the two optional parameters *screen_name* and *screen_class*, as well as any custom event parameters you want to include.

For Android make sure to log it on the **onResume** method, it should be something like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName);
  bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, screenClass);
  bundle.putString(MyAppAnalyticsConstants.Param.TOPIC, topic);
  mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle);
}
```

You could check out this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#java) to know more on manually tracking of screens in Firebase.